# How could i get pandas groupby not to take indices in account but values of my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I have a dataFrame with dates and prices, for example :

| date | price |
| --- | --- |
| 2006 | 500 |
| 2007 | 2000 |
| 2007 | 3400 |
| 2006 | 5000 |

and i want to group my data by year so that i obtain :

| 2007 | 2006 |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 500 |
| 3400 | 5000 |

This is the code i tried :
`df = my_old_df.groupby(['date'])`
`my_desried_df = pd.DataFrame(data=df.groups)`

but i obtain what i desire but with the indices of the values not the value (the price inmy case) i expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) :

```
out = (
        df.assign(idx= df.groupby("date").cumcount().add(1))
            .pivot(index="idx", columns="date", values="price")
            .rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output :
​

```
print(out)

   2006  2007
0   500  2000
1  5000  3400
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
g = df.groupby('date')['price'].agg(list)
out = pd.DataFrame(columns=g.index, data=g.values.tolist())
print(out)

date  2006  2007
0      500  5000
1     2000  3400
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did ? Because i got and exception : The columns passed (indices) as parameter are less than the dataFrame values